# How can I use a controller to render a form in a template file?

Tags: theming, forms, page-controller

I'm looking to add a form inside a custom template.

#### opacsearchmodule.routing.yml

```
opacsearchmodule.route1:
  path: '/form-test/object-builder'
  defaults:
    _form: '\Drupal\opacsearchmodule\Form\opacSearchForm'
  requirements:
    _access: 'TRUE'

opacsearchmodule.login:
  path: '/form-login/object-builder'
  defaults:
    _form: '\Drupal\opacsearchmodule\Form\loginForm'
  requirements:
    _access: 'TRUE'
```

#### LoginForm.php

```
 public function buildForm(array $form, FormStateInterface $form_state)
  {
    // TODO: Implement buildForm() method.
    $form['#theme'] = 'front_page';

    $form['user_name'] = array(
      '#type' => 'textfield',
      '#title' => t(' '),
      '#label_display' => before,
      '#attributes' => array(
        'placeholder' =>  t(''),
        'style'=>'',
        'class' => ['form-control']
      ),
      '#required' => TRUE,

    );


    $form['password'] = array(
      '#type' => 'password',
      '#title' => t(' '),
      '#label_display' => before,
      '#attributes' => array(
        'placeholder' =>  t(''),
        'style'=>'',
        'class' => ['form-control']
      ),
      '#required' => TRUE,
    );
```

#### opacsearchmodule.module

```
function opacsearchmodule_theme($existing, $type, $theme, $path)
{
    return array(
        'opac_search'=> array(
            'variables'=>array('branches'=>NULL,'mattypes'=>NULL,'title'=>'','searchresults'=>NULL)
        ),
        'search_results'=> array(
            'variables'=>array('branches'=>NULL,'mattypes'=>NULL,'title'=>'','searchresults'=>NULL)
        ),
        'book_details'=> array(
          'variables'=>array('branches'=>NULL,'mattypes'=>NULL,'title'=>'','searchresults'=>NULL,'id'=>NULL)
        ),
      'category_page'=> array(
            'variables'=>array()
        ),

      'front_page' => array(
        'template' =>'front_page',
        'render element' => 'form'
      ),
    );
 }
```

The controller contains the following code.

```
 public function openLoginPage(){
    $form = \Drupal::formBuilder()->getForm('Drupal\opacsearchmodule\Form\loginForm');

    return [
      '#theme' => 'front_page',
      'form' => $form,
    ];
  }
```

The template filename is front-page.html.twig. If I open form using path registered inside routing.yml file, it works; if I try to use it inside a custom template it doesn't work.

Comment: As side note, you don't translate a space, and `'#label_display' => before` is not correct, in PHP.

Comment: You are using #theme `front_page` twice. Since this template is defined in hook_theme() to handle the form elements use it only in the form build. Does it work if you remove it from the controller? If you want a template in the controller use a different one and then put the form in a template variable `'#form' => $form,`